# Declaring a static FileWriter and FileReader

Tags: java, file

I want to declare a static FileWriter and FileReader instance so I can use the same one throughout a large program. Eclipse tells me that an IOException must be thrown. How can I throw an exception for the declaration?

```
static FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
static BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
static FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
static BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Don't do that. It's asking for all sorts of trouble and is a maintenance and debugging nightmare. Use something like dependency injection instead.

Comment: You should really rework your design so these static variables are not used.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
static File file = new File("");
static FileWriter fileWriter;
static BufferedWriter writer;
static FileReader fileReader;
static BufferedReader reader;

static {
    try {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
        writer = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Bruno. So by doing that, I can use the instances without having to call a method in my other methods? Just wondering and making sure.

Comment: I suggest throwing an ExceptionInInitializeError (with `e` as its constructor argument) in the `catch` block.  This promotes _fail fast_ behavior - the program will halt immediately if the `IOException` is thrown.

Comment: @DannyDaglas good point, updated the answer with your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Just put a `throws IOException` after the method declaration.

i.e.: `public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { ... }`

That's it.
Though it is not elegant to use it this way...

Answer (score 0):

Put the initialization in a static block as follows:

```
public final class MyUtil {
    static FileWriter fileWriter;
    static BufferedWriter writer;
    static FileReader fileReader;
    static BufferedReader reader;

    static {
        try {
            File file = new File("<pathToFile>");
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
            writer = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
            fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
           // Handle the exception here
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this will kind of global state to a file writer/reader can cause issues in a multi-threaded environment, so you might want to make sure there is some synchronization to handle this.